# Cloudant json index vs text index

Tags: indexing, couchdb, cloudant, nosql

Hi I am trying to understand json index vs text index in Cloudant. Now I know using

```
{ "index": {}, "type": "text" }
```

Will make the entire document searchable. But what is the difference between say,

```
{
  "index": {
    "fields": [
      "title"
    ]
  },
  "type": "json"
}
```

and

```
{
    "index": {
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "title",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ]
    },
    "name": "title-text",
    "type": "text"
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

the `json` type:

- leverages the Map phase of MapReduce
- will build and query faster than a text type for a fixed key
- no `bookmark` field
- cannot use combination or array logical operators such as `$regex` as the basis of a query
- only equality operators such as `$eq`, `$gt`, `$gte`, `$lt`, and `$lte` (but not `$ne`) can be used as the basis of a query
- might end up doing more work in memory for complex queries
- sorting fields must be indexed

the `text` type:

- leverages a Lucene search index
- permits indexing all fields in documents automatically with a single simple command
- provides more flexibility to perform adhoc queries and sort across multiple keys
- permits you to use any operator as a basis for query in a selector
- type (`:string`, `:number`) sometimes need to be appended to sort field

from: https://docs.cloudant.com/cloudant_query.html

> If you know exactly what data you want to look for, or you want to
>   keep storage and processing requirements to a minimum, you can specify
>   how the index is created, by making it of type json.
>
> But for maximum possible flexibility when looking for data, you would
>   typically create an index of type text.

additional information:
https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/docs/cloudant/get-started/use-cloudant-query/